# How is Make it Happen implemented?

Tags: crowd-funding

It looks like it is a good implementation crowdfunding that I could use to fund projects for my org at low cost (just credit card charges). Is there any info about its implementation on the civicrm website.

Answer (score 2):

I read your question differently to Andy.

The MIH itself is simply a civicrm contribution page.

But there are also MIH 'content types' and the page at https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen is then a View (Drupal) based on the above Content Type and I suspect there is a fair bit of custom stuff happening in that View which means an 'export' of it won't give you it in a box.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. A little more info about any custom stuff in the view would be useful. Just an export of the view would be a useful start. However the info on how to submit a MIH is also useful - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While old, this covers a lot of it: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Make+it+Happen#MakeitHappen-HowdoIsubmitanMIHcandidate?.